# What are some useful things you can do with Mvc Modelbinders?

Tags: mvc, asp.net-mvc

It occurs to me that the ModelBinder mechanism in ASP MVC

```
public interface IModelBinder {
  object BindModel(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ModelBindingContext bindingContext);
}
```

Is insanely powerful.  What are some cool uses of this mechanism that you've done/seen?

I guess since the concept is similar in other frameworks there's no reason to limit it to Asp Mvc

Answer (score 2):

Consider a custom type called `TimeInterval` that is stored as a `double`, but is displayed as **hh.mm.ss.ffffff** where `ffffff` is fractional seconds.  With custom binding, it is possible to show the binder how to properly parse and display these numbers, without having to write custom code in the controller.

```
// This class implements a custom data type for data binding.
public class TimeInterval
{
    double _value;

    // Constructor
    public TimeInterval(string value)
    {
        // Extension method parses hh.mm.ss.ffffff string value to double.
        _value = value.ToSeconds();
    }
    // Constructor
    public TimeInterval(double value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }
    public string GetText()
    {
        // Extension method formats double value as hh.mm.ss.ffffff time string.
        return _value.ToTimeString();
    }
    public double? GetValue()
    {
        return _value;
    }
}

// This class implements custom binding for the TimeInterval custom type.  
// It is registered in Global.asax 
public class TimeIntervalBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        string value = GetAttemptedValue(bindingContext);

        if (value == "")
            return null;

        return new TimeInterval(value);
    }

    private static string GetAttemptedValue(ModelBindingContext context)
    {
        ValueProviderResult value = context.ValueProvider[context.ModelName];
        return value.AttemptedValue ?? string.Empty;
    }
}

// in Global.asax:
protected void Application_Start()
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(TimeInterval), new TimeIntervalBinder());
}
```

Now binding happens automatically for the new custom type.

Answer (score 0):

I've used model binders to localize content based on session state information. By the time the controller knows anything, the content has already been set according to the user's preferred locale.